# Add styling to expression in Object Literal in React

Tags: css, reactjs, object-literal

This is what I have:

```
const weight = "bold";
const someBool = true;

return (
  {someBool &&
  `This should be ${weight}.`
  }
)
```

I need to add styling to the expression in the object literal. I tried this, but it is returning as `This should be [object object].` on the UI:

```
`This should be ${<span fontWeight="bold">{weight}</span>}.`
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: `\`This should be <span fontWeight="bold">${weight}</span>.\``

Comment: I tried this but the span part is not being applied. It's printing with all the letters.

Comment: The `weight` variable is the only templated value to be replaced. The rest is just HTML.

Comment: How are you using that return value? It might have to done with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or whatever that is.

Comment: It's being returned directly to the UI. It's the return statement for a functional component. It's inside a table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to group your plain text and element (`span`) without having a real wrapper element.
I use `React.Fragment` below because I don't think stackoverflow's babel parser can parse the "[short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)" (`<>` / `</>`), but you can also use that in your real application.

In the example below, I used the `style` prop as well to apply the bolding. Passing a `fontWeight` prop doesn't work out of the box, you'd need a custom element or something like [styled-system](https://styled-system.com/).

```js
function App() {
  const weight = "bold";
  const someBool = true;

  return (
    someBool && (
      <React.Fragment>
        This should be <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{weight}</span>.
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
const weight = "bold";
const someBool = true;
const style = { fontWeight: "bold" };

 return (
  someBool && (
  <>
    This should be <span style={style}>{weight}</span>.
  </>
   )
 )}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

There are 4 ways to style your component. Please visit this for deep knowledge.
https://medium.com/technofunnel/4-ways-to-add-styles-to-react-component-37c2a2034e3e